# как с помощью веб-консоли браузера получить ссылки на картинки из контейнеров

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите как с помощью веб-консоли браузера получить все ссылки картинок находящиеся в td class="cell" [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Скажите в каждом ли эдементе td с классом cell такая таблица, или только в одном?

Тогда можно сделать так.

```
var $cells = $('td.cell');
$.each($cells, function (index, $cell) {
    var $images = $cell.find('img'); // здесь у тебя есть массив всех jquery объектов картинок, можешь с ними делать то, что хочешь
});
```

Можешь дальше воспользоваться советом @Grundy как получить url

Comment: Если у вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/115022)

Comment: Я просто хотел сказать, что немного неясно условие

Comment: @ИльяСавич, а есть какая-то разница?

Comment: Да в каждом элементе

Comment: это код не сработает: children возвращает только прямых потомков, а внутри `td.cell` лежит только table

Comment: получаю VM776:2 Uncaught TypeError: $.each is not a function

Comment: @Новичок, подключена ли jQuery? если подключена - такой ошибки не будет

Comment: Вместо children воспользуйтесь find

Answer (score 0):

Для выборки можно использовать [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), который принимает css селектор, например так:

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('td.cell img');
```

Далее следует получить список значений атрибута src, можно воспользоваться [методом map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), для этого нужно получить из коллекции массив, например с помощью [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```
var urls = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td.cell img')).map(el=>el.src);
```

jquery вариант:

```
var urls = $('td.cell img').map(function(){ return this.src}).get();
```

Comment: Ввел эти две команды, потом ввел copy(imgs); что бы скопировать в буфер, но в буфере оказались такие строки: {
  "0": {},
  "1": {},
  "2": {},
  "3": {},
  "4": {},
  "5": {},
  "6": {},
  "7": {},
  "8": {},
  "9": {},....................и тд

Comment: @Новичок, что именно ты хочешь скопировать? И еще раз прочитай ответ: imgs - коллекция элементов, ее нельзя скопировать, потому что, элементы нельзя сериализовать

Comment: Я хочу скопировать все ссылки на картинки

Comment: @Новичок, можешь просто добавить их на страницу в какой нибудь временный элемент и скопировать с нее

Answer (score 0):

В новых браузерах можно использовать forEach для NodeList, например,

```
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(img => console.log(img.src))
```

выводит ссылки на все изображения в консоль.